# What's the probability that the numbers on the license plate of a random car add up to 21?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a license plate with 4 digits. What is the probability that those digits add up to 21? I do not know how to find the number of ways you can have digits which add up to 21.

Comment: Write a little program in your favorite language....

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: What about restrictions ? Can it start with $0$, for instance ?

Comment: There is a simple set of recursions you can use here....let $F(d,n)$ be the number of ways a $d-$digit plate could sum to $n$ we want $F(4,21)$ but it is easy to see that $F(d,n)=\sum_{k=n-9}^nF(d-1, k)$, and of course $F(1,n)=1$ if $0≤n≤9$ and $=0$ otherwise.  That is easily automated, though the pencil and paper computation would be tedious.